# How to detect orientation change?

Tags: ios, swift, orientation-changes

I am using Swift and I want to be able to load a UIViewController when I rotate to landscape, can anyone point me in the right direction?

I Can't find anything online and a little bit confused by the documentation.

Comment: I suppose that the API has not changed so it should be "didRotateToOrientation" and "willRotateToOrientation", something like that, take a look in the Apple documentation

Comment: Hi @mArm.ch, thanks for the quick reply! So how would I implement this? (This is my first app... I'm very new to IOS) :)

Comment: I reposted as answer, for other people. Can you accept it if it's ok for you ?

Comment: Check this one if you want to check orientation when the app launched.     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34452650/in-swift-how-to-get-the-device-orientation-correctly-right-after-its-launched/49058588#49058588

Answer (score 221, accepted):

Here's how I got it working:

In `AppDelegate.swift` inside the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`  function I put:

```swift
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(AppDelegate.rotated), name: UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
```

and then inside the AppDelegate class I put the following function:

```swift
func rotated() {
    if UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(UIDevice.current.orientation) {
        print("Landscape")
    }

    if UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(UIDevice.current.orientation) {
        print("Portrait")
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried adding the addObserver in the AppDelegate but kept getting a SIGABRT in CoreFoundation with an unrecognised selector.
However, when I moved the addObserver to a viewDidLoad in my first view it worked perfectly. 
Just for information if anyone comes across the same issue.

Comment: Bare in mind that you have to call:
UIDevice.currentDevice().beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications() otherwise you wont get any notification.

Comment: Im new to coding but shouldn't `selector` have a string format of `"rotated:"`??

Comment: Im pretty sure thats only if you are accepting arguments (which `rotated()` doesn't)

Comment: Awesome. I know this is a bit old, but it did help me when overriding the viewDidLayoutSubviews(){} method in my view controller. Definitely worth the upvote thanks!

Comment: Selector always should accept one argument, as per doc: `Selector that specifies the message the receiver sends notificationObserver to notify it of the notification posting. The method specified by notificationSelector must have one and only one argument (an instance of NSNotification).`

Comment: Be careful because `UIDeviceOrientation` is something different to `UIInterfaceOrientation`.. This is because `UIDeviceOrientation` also detects face down and face up orientations meaning that your code can jump between portrait and landscape randomly if your device is resting on an almost flat but slightly uneven surface (i.e rocking on the protruding camera of the 6/6s)

Comment: This method DO NOT WORK if the phone disabled auto rotation.

Comment: @chengsam the question is about auto rotation though

Comment: To expand on the comment from @liamnichols - if you tilt the device slightly forward an backward (*without changing the portrait/landscape orientation*), the `UIDeviceOrientationDidChange` notification is sent. Although the screen orientation is unchanged, the device orientation has changed in 3D space, therefore you get the notification

Comment: for swift 4.2 you will need to do something like this: `NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(AppDelegate.rotated), name: UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification, object: nil)`

Comment: How to override AppDelegate.rotated parameter to get rid of UIViewController ??

Comment: it returns false when in flat position but view is landscape

Comment: Is there a way to get UIInterfaceOrientation through a notification?

Comment: This solution is very good. Guys that are saying to put alo of code in AppDelegate I advice to create a singleton and use inside of this two methods.

Comment: Here notification name is update:         Use -`NSNotification.Name.UIDeviceOrientationDidChange`

Comment: In my case, I am seeing this notification being called also in the case whenever a native popup is dismissed. So I think we should avoid using it

Answer (score 192):

According to the [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontentcontainer/1621466-viewwilltransition):

> This method is called when the view controller's view's size is changed by its parent (i.e. for the root view controller when its window rotates or is resized).

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
    
    if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape {
        print("Landscape")
    }
    if UIDevice.current.orientation.isFlat {
        print("Flat")
    } else {
        print("Portrait")
    }
}
```

Comment: This will be called BEFORE the rotation. If you need e.g. the frame size after the rotation this solution will not work.

Comment: didn't work in extension. landscape or portrait still print "portraight"

Comment: This method DO NOT WORK if the phone disabled auto rotation.

Comment: on iPad, since size class is the same regular for both landscape and portrait, this method is never called.

Comment: This will also fail if the device returns isFlat. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uideviceorientation/2981866-isflat

Comment: It's painful to see all those people forgetting to call super everytime... People needs to understand what override means.

Answer (score 67):

I need to detect rotation while using the camera with `AVFoundation`, and found that the `didRotate` (**now deprecated**) & `willTransition` methods were unreliable for my needs. Using the notification posted by David did work, but is not current for Swift 3.x & above.

The following makes use of a closure, which appears to be Apple's preference going forward.

```
var didRotate: (Notification) -> Void = { notification in
        switch UIDevice.current.orientation {
        case .landscapeLeft, .landscapeRight:
            print("landscape")
        case .portrait, .portraitUpsideDown:
            print("Portrait")
        default:
            print("other (such as face up & down)")
        }
    }
```

**To set up the notification**:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification,
                                       object: nil,
                                       queue: .main,
                                       using: didRotate)
```

**To tear down the notification**:

```
NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self,
                                          name: UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification,
                                          object: nil)
```

**Regarding the deprecation statement**, my initial comment was misleading, so I wanted to update that. As noted, the usage of `@objc` inference has been deprecated, which in turn was needed to use a `#selector`. By using a closure instead, this can be avoided and you now have a solution that should avoid a crash due to calling an invalid selector.

Comment: Do you have reference to where Apple talking about discouraging the use of #selector in Swift 4?  I would like to read up on why they are saying this.

Comment: @jeffjv Certainly, I do not have a direct link to an Apple document, but I did include a screenshot of the compiler warning that XCode provides if you use the previous approach.

Comment: I have added a link to swift-evolution that discusses the change.

Comment: @CodeBender: The compiler warning does not mean what you suggest. #selector  is not being depreciated, only "@objc" inference. This means that when using a function as a #selector you have to explicitly mark it, so that the compiler will generate the additional correct code because the compiler will no longer try infer it from your usage. Hence, if you add "@obj" to your rotate() func in your Swift 3.0 solution, the code will compile without the warning.

Comment: Thanks @Mythlandia, I updated the answer to resolve the confusion over my initial statement.

Comment: how to access class variable or function inside didRotate var? any idea

Comment: How do I use this in something like: if portrait { runFunctionA } else if landscape { runFunctionB } else {runFunctionC } ?

Answer (score 21):

Using `-orientation` property of `UIDevice` is not correct (even if it could work in most of cases) and could lead to some bugs, for instance `UIDeviceOrientation` consider also the orientation of the device if it is face up or down, there is no direct pair in `UIInterfaceOrientation` enum for those values.
Furthermore, if you lock your app in some particular orientation, UIDevice will give you the device orientation without taking that into account.
On the other side iOS8 has deprecated the `interfaceOrientation` property on `UIViewController` class. 
There are 2 options available to detect the interface orientation:

- Use the status bar orientation
- Use size classes, on iPhone if they are not overridden they could give you a way to understand the current interface orientation

What is still missing is a way to understand the direction of a    change of interface orientation, that is very important during    animations.
 In the session of WWDC 2014 "View controller    advancement in iOS8" the speaker provides a solution to that problem    too, using the method that replaces    `-will/DidRotateToInterfaceOrientation`.

Here the proposed solution partially implemented, more info [here](http://blog.inferis.org/blog/2015/04/27/ios8-and-interfaceorientation/):

```
func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        let orientation = orientationFromTransform(coordinator.targetTransform())
        let oldOrientation = UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarOrientation
        myWillRotateToInterfaceOrientation(orientation,duration: duration)
        coordinator.animateAlongsideTransition({ (ctx) in
            self.myWillAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation(orientation,
            duration:duration)
            }) { (ctx) in
                self.myDidAnimateFromInterfaceOrientation(oldOrientation)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 13):

Since iOS 8 this is the correct way to do it.

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)

    coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: { context in
        // This is called during the animation
    }, completion: { context in
        // This is called after the rotation is finished. Equal to deprecated `didRotate`
    })
}
```

Comment: Much better answer than `NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(AppDelegate.rotated), name: UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification, object: nil)`. The issue with UIDeviceOrientation is that it detects face down and face up orientations which we don't need.

Answer (score 12):

I know this question is for `Swift`, but since it's one of the top links for a Google search and if you're looking for the same code in `Objective-C`:

```
// add the observer
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(rotated:) name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];

// remove the observer
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];

// method signature
- (void)rotated:(NSNotification *)notification {
    // do stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Easy, this works in iOS8 and 9 / Swift 2 / Xcode7, just put this code inside your viewcontroller.swift. It will print the screen dimensions with every orientation change, you can put your own code instead:

```
override func didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation(fromInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation) {
        getScreenSize()
    }
    var screenWidth:CGFloat=0
    var screenHeight:CGFloat=0
    func getScreenSize(){
        screenWidth=UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width
        screenHeight=UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height
        print("SCREEN RESOLUTION: "+screenWidth.description+" x "+screenHeight.description)
    }
```

Comment: This function was deprecated, use "viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator: " instead

Comment: Beside being deprecated, `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation()` doesn't work reliably. It misses some rotations. `iewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:` works ok.

Comment: @Andrej Lots of things are now deprecated thanks to Swift 3

Answer (score 11):

I like checking the orientation notification because you can add this feature in any class, no needs to be a view or a view controller. Even in your app delegate.

**SWIFT 5:**

```
    //ask the system to start notifying when interface change
    UIDevice.current.beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications()
    //add the observer
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
        self,
        selector: #selector(orientationChanged(notification:)),
        name: UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification,
        object: nil)
```

than caching the notification

```
    @objc func orientationChanged(notification : NSNotification) {
        //your code there
    }
```

Answer (score 10):

Use the new 
[viewWillTransitionToSize(_:withTransitionCoordinator:)](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIContentContainer_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIContentContainer/viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:)

Answer (score 8):

In Objective C

```
-(void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator
```

In swift

```
func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator)
```

Override this method to detect the orientation change.

Answer (score 8):

**Swift 3 | UIDeviceOrientationDidChange Notification Observed Too Often**

The following code prints "deviceDidRotate" every time your device changes orientation in 3D space - regardless of a change from portrait to landscape orientation. For example, if you hold your phone in portrait orientation and tilt it forward and backward - deviceDidRotate() is called repeatedly.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
        self, 
        selector:  #selector(deviceDidRotate), 
        name: .UIDeviceOrientationDidChange, 
        object: nil
    )
}

func deviceDidRotate() {
    print("deviceDidRotate")
}
```

To work around this you could hold the previous device orientation and check for a change in deviceDidRotate().

```
var previousDeviceOrientation: UIDeviceOrientation = UIDevice.current.orientation

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
        self, 
        selector:  #selector(deviceDidRotate), 
        name: .UIDeviceOrientationDidChange, 
        object: nil
    )
}

func deviceDidRotate() {
    if UIDevice.current.orientation == previousDeviceOrientation { return }
    previousDeviceOrientation = UIDevice.current.orientation
    print("deviceDidRotate")
}
```

Or you can use a different notification that only gets called when the device changes from landscape to portrait. In this case you'd want to use the `UIApplicationDidChangeStatusBarOrientation` notification.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
        self, 
        selector:  #selector(deviceDidRotate), 
        name: .UIApplicationDidChangeStatusBarOrientation, 
        object: nil
    )
}

func deviceDidRotate() {
    print("deviceDidRotate")
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
override func didRotate(from fromInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation) {
    //swift 3
    getScreenSize()
}


func getScreenSize(){
   let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
   let  screenHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
    print("SCREEN RESOLUTION: \(screenWidth.description) x \(screenHeight.description)")
}
```

Comment: Cleanest answer. Worked for me.

Comment: This is now deprecated

Answer (score 6):

**Full working implementation of how to detect orientation change in Swift 3.0.**

I chose to use this implementation because phone orientations of `face up` and `face down` were important to me, and I wanted the view to change only once I knew the orientation was in the specified position.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //1
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(deviceOrientationDidChange), name: NSNotification.Name.UIDeviceOrientationDidChange, object: nil)

    }

    deinit {
        //3
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIDeviceOrientationDidChange, object: nil)
    }

    func deviceOrientationDidChange() {
        //2
        switch UIDevice.current.orientation {
        case .faceDown:
            print("Face down")
        case .faceUp:
            print("Face up")
        case .unknown:
            print("Unknown")
        case .landscapeLeft:
            print("Landscape left")
        case .landscapeRight:
            print("Landscape right")
        case .portrait:
            print("Portrait")
        case .portraitUpsideDown:
            print("Portrait upside down")
        }
    }

}
```

The important pieces to note are:

1. You listen to the DeviceOrientationDidChange notification stream and tie it to the function deviceOrientationDidChange
2. You then switch on the device orientation, be sure to take notice that there is an `unknown` orientation at times.
3. Like any notification, before the viewController is deinitialized, make sure to stop observing the notification stream.

Hope someone finds this helpful.

Comment: Thank you
, great

Comment: So I'm confused, currently all my views adjust based on portrait to landscape, but it doesnt change if the device is face-up? How would I use your above code to achieve the same effect when its face-up!?

Comment: Can you give a little more context?  I'm not sure what effect you're referring to.  This code works to simply detect orientation.  If you're using multiple methods for detecting orientation you might run into trouble.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to do something AFTER the rotation is complete, you can use the `UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator` completion handler like this

```
public override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)

    // Hook in to the rotation animation completion handler
    coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: nil) { (_) in
        // Updates to your UI...
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

**Swift 4:**

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(deviceRotated), name: UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
}

@objc func deviceRotated(){
    if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape {
        //Code here
    } else {
        //Code here
    }
}
```

A lot of answers dont help when needing to detect across various view controllers. This one does the trick.

Comment: You also need to check if device was rotated while the view controller was disappeared (in case of other view controller is opened above current). In fact, you can skip `viewWillDisappear` and add `addObserver` in `viewDidLoad`. iOS unsubscribes view controller automatically.

Comment: you forgot `UIDevice.current.orientation.isFlat`

Comment: @Joel this does not work when the Phone Orientation is Locked. Any idea how that can be fixed?

Answer (score 4):

Check if rotation had changed with: `viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator)`

With the `coordinator.animateAlongsideTransition(nil) { (UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext)` you can check if the transition is finished.

See code below:

```
override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {

    super.viewWillTransitionToSize(size, withTransitionCoordinator: coordinator)

    coordinator.animateAlongsideTransition(nil) { (UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext) in
        // if you want to execute code after transition finished
        print("Transition finished")
    }

    if size.height < size.width {
        // Landscape
        print("Landscape")
    } else {
        // Portrait
        print("Portrait")
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is an easy way to detect the device orientation: (**Swift 3**)

```
override func willRotate(to toInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation, duration: TimeInterval) {
            handleViewRotaion(orientation: toInterfaceOrientation)
        }

    //MARK: - Rotation controls
    func handleViewRotaion(orientation:UIInterfaceOrientation) -> Void {
        switch orientation {
        case .portrait :
            print("portrait view")
            break
        case .portraitUpsideDown :
            print("portraitUpsideDown view")
            break
        case .landscapeLeft :
            print("landscapeLeft view")
            break
        case .landscapeRight :
            print("landscapeRight view")
            break
        case .unknown :
            break
        }
    }
```

Comment: `willRotate` is deprecated now, better use `viewWillTransition`.

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 5**

Setup class to receive notifications of device orientation change:

```swift
class MyClass {

    ...

    init (...) {

        ...

        super.init(...)

        // subscribe to device orientation change notifications
        UIDevice.current.beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications()
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(orientationChanged), name: UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification, object: nil)

        ...

    }

    ...

}
```

Setup handler code:

```swift
@objc extension MyClass {
    func orientationChanged(_ notification: NSNotification) {
        let device = notification.object as! UIDevice
        let deviceOrientation = device.orientation

        switch deviceOrientation {
        case .landscapeLeft:   //do something for landscape left
        case .landscapeRight:  //do something for landscape right
        case .portrait:        //do something for portrait
        case .portraitUpsideDown: //do something for portrait upside-down 
        case .faceDown:        //do something for face down
        case .faceUp:          //do something for face up
        case .unknown:         //handle unknown
        @unknown default:      //handle unknown default
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

My approach is similar to what [bpedit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36454000/1776993) shows above, but with an iOS 9+ focus. I wanted to change the scope of the [FSCalendar](https://github.com/WenchaoD/FSCalendar%20FSCalendar) when the view rotates.

```
override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransitionToSize(size, withTransitionCoordinator: coordinator)

    coordinator.animateAlongsideTransition({ (context) in
        if size.height < size.width {
            self.calendar.setScope(.Week, animated: true)
            self.calendar.appearance.cellShape = .Rectangle
        }
        else {
            self.calendar.appearance.cellShape = .Circle
            self.calendar.setScope(.Month, animated: true)

        }

        }, completion: nil)
}
```

This below worked, but I felt sheepish about it :)

```
coordinator.animateAlongsideTransition({ (context) in
        if size.height < size.width {
            self.calendar.scope = .Week
            self.calendar.appearance.cellShape = .Rectangle
        }
        }) { (context) in
            if size.height > size.width {
                self.calendar.scope = .Month
                self.calendar.appearance.cellShape = .Circle
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I use `UIUserInterfaceSizeClass` to detect a orientation changed in a `UIViewController` class just like that:

```
override func willTransition(to newCollection: UITraitCollection, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {

    let isiPadLandscapePortrait = newCollection.horizontalSizeClass == .regular && newCollection.verticalSizeClass == .regular
    let isiPhonePlustLandscape = newCollection.horizontalSizeClass == .regular && newCollection.verticalSizeClass == .compact
    let isiPhonePortrait = newCollection.horizontalSizeClass == .compact && newCollection.verticalSizeClass == .regular
    let isiPhoneLandscape = newCollection.horizontalSizeClass == .compact && newCollection.verticalSizeClass == .compact

     if isiPhonePortrait {
         // do something...
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**For Swift 3**

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape {
        //Landscape
    }
    else if UIDevice.current.orientation.isFlat {
        //isFlat
    }
    else {
        //Portrait
    }
}
```

Comment: you forgot `UIDevice.current.orientation.isFlat`

Answer (score 1):

With iOS 13.1.2, orientation always return 0 until device is rotated. I need to call UIDevice.current.beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications() before any rotation event occurs to get actual rotation.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(OrientationDidChange:) name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];
}

-(void)OrientationDidChange:(NSNotification*)notification {
  UIDeviceOrientation Orientation=[[UIDevice currentDevice]orientation];

  if(Orientation==UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft || Orientation==UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
    NSLog(@"Landscape");
  } else if(Orientation==UIDeviceOrientationPortrait) {
    NSLog(@"Potrait Mode");
  }
}
```

NOTE: Just use this code to identify UIViewController is in which orientation

Comment: Your code is not working in project. do I need to do anything else as well?

Answer (score 0):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(MyController.rotated), name: UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
//...
}

@objc
private func rotated() {
    if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape {

    } else if UIDevice.current.orientation.isPortrait {

    }

    //or you can check orientation separately UIDevice.current.orientation
    //portrait, portraitUpsideDown, landscapeLeft, landscapeRight... 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Iphone 15 pro traits on landscape orientation is ***compact*** and ***compact***. Iphone 15 pro max is regular in horizantal trait on lanscape mode. It is so strange from Apple!