# what is the simplest way to detect a rotation change?

Tags: ios, swift, view

I am writing a graphing app - Landscape positions the content within the portrait's coordinate system. What is the simplest way for my viewController to detect an orientation change?

*edit* I am aware there is a similar question from sept 2014, but the solution appears code specific - could someone clarify what the *simplest way to detect rotation* might be? (code explanation good too)

### I tried the implementation but keep getting a "expected declaration" error on NSNotificationCenter

(and for clarity's sake, here's the referenced solution:)

In AppDelegate.swift inside the "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions":

```
`NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "rotated", name: UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification, object: nil)`
```

in the AppDelegate class:

```
func rotated()
{
    if(UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation))
    {            
        println("landscape")
    }
    if(UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation))
    {
        println("Portrait")
    }
}
```

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25666269/ios8-swift-how-to-detect-orientation-change

Comment: I had checked that thread before asking my question - I don't have a appdelegate.swift file and am not clear as to how to go about it. furthermore, I am asking for the simplest way... I was hoping there was something more straightforward.

Comment: You can put that code wherever you want. It doesn't need to be in the AppDelegate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the **simplest** way I found to react to a rotation, which should be an easy implementation for most - the overridden function gets called "any time a view's frame changed and its subviews were thus  re-layed out" (credit: Stanford CS193p slides)

in the viewController (of the view that will rotate):

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    // code to handle rotation details
}
```

Comment: you should not put anything in viewDidLayoutSubviews as you don't know when it is called or how many times it is called.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with this method. If you have many subviews added on your main view this function will be called many times.

I think the best way is:

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    // Your Processing
}
```

Moreover, you have parameters to help you in your handling.