# detect when the device is rotated swift

Tags: swift, keyboard, ios9, screen-orientation

I'm  developing a custom keyboard and I've added the buttons programmatically and they're doing great but when the device rotate the buttons in the bottom disappear -because of the changing of the screen size- so I need to reposition the buttons in new positions -I wanna have four lines instead of six - when the device rotate , how can I do that ?

Comment: use autolayout and constraints

Comment: Thanks @DevTonio for the answer but how can use autolayout and constraints for the keyboard ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

1. You can use Autoresizing to change position according to size of
   screen and orientation.
2. Set custom frame for button

Ex:

```
your_button.frame=CGRectMake(0,0,100,100) // (x,y,width,height)
```

Comment: my problem is how do I know what is the size of the screen
I tried to print the width but it didn't work , I tried this code :
`print(self.view.frame.width)`

Comment: Its Very simple to get screen size:                                                                           let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds;
screenSize.origin;
        let screenWidth = screenSize.width;
        let screenHeight = screenSize.height;
        
        print("The main page width : %f",screenSize.width);
        
        print("The main page height : %f",screenSize.height);

Comment: that's great it worked! but how can I detect when the user rotate his device and reposition the button ? is there a method that works when the user rotate his device ?

Comment: If you want to detect screen orientation then ref this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25666269/ios8-swift-how-to-detect-orientation-change

Comment: my problem here is that when I use the app I'll know if the user did rotate the device but I'm developing a custom keyboard so that the user can use it in other applications which means that I can't use the AppDelegate for that :(

Comment: Can you able to explain about your project?

Comment: I'm developing a custom keyboard, which means that I'll design a keyboard that can work in any application so you  can use the keyboard to write a tweet in twitter or to post a status in Facebook and so on

Comment: Great! Then where you go to set your button?

Comment: sorry I didn't understand you question ^_^!

Comment: Okay cool, Tell about button position while rotating.Did you have any image for ref

Comment: sorry I tried to understand your question but I couldn't , if you're asking how to design a custom keyboard you can see this tutorial : http://www.appcoda.com/custom-keyboard-tutorial/