# How to include a third variable when programmatically laying out constraints in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

[image: Two buttons in UIView]

I essentially have two buttons laid out in a larger view, and I want the distance between the buttons to be equal to a multiple of the larger view. For example, I want to do something like:

```
var buttonOneRightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: button1, attribute: .Right, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: button2, attribute: .Left, multiplier: 1.0, constant: -largerView.frame.width/10)
```

Which works well in one orientation, but doesn't update when the view size changes (e.g., device is rotated).

I think I would want to have it calculate largerView.frame.width every time the view is updated, as opposed to treat it like a constant, but not sure how to do that!

Answer (score 0):

Add an observer for the device orientation change event in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method:

```
  NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(TheClassYouWantTheMethodToBeFired, selector: "rotated", name: UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
```

Then, compute the layout inside the `rotated` new method

[How to detect orientation change?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25666269/ios8-swift-how-to-detect-orientation-change)

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit new to Swift - where would you put this if you are using an extension? I'm creating a custom third-party keyboard.