# How to rotate button when device orientation changes in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, rotation, device-orientation

How can I just rotate the buttons when my device is in portrait or landscape mode? I know something like that:

```
button.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI))
```

But where I have to call it up in my code?
I don't want to set my device in landscape mode, I just want to rotate the icons when it should be in landscape mode.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25666269/ios8-swift-how-to-detect-orientation-change

Answer (score 1):

You should override func

```
viewWillTransitionToSize(_ size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator:UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator)
```

And call transform there

Don't forget to assign `CGAffineTransformIdentity` when rotated back

More about rotation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIContentContainer_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIContentContainer/viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is `viewDidLoad` add this line of code bellow:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(rotate), name: UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
```

and then in function rotate in case of device orientation do some code like this:

```
func rotate(){
    if UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation) {
    //your code here in landscape mode
    }
if UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation){
    //your code in portrait mode
    }
}
```

this solution is simple and really easy to do.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you know how to "rotate" the buttons already, so I'll just tell you how to know that the device has rotated.

In a view controller, override `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation`:

```
override func willRotateToInterfaceOrientation(toInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation, duration: NSTimeInterval) {

}
```

In the method body, you can check the value of `toInterfaceOrientation` to know which orientation the device is rotating to. For example:

```
switch toInterfaceOrientation {
    case Portrait:
        // some code here...
    default:
        break
}
```

Comment: This is deprecated

Comment: @RanLearns Yes, and this is from 4 years ago.