# How can I lock camera view orientation to landscape in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, camera, orientation

I'd like to fix my Camera View in landscape Mode. And also show an alert when user rotate view to portrait. is there any solution available ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this in your view controller:

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape {
        print("will turn to landscape")
    } else {
        print("will turn to portrait")
        //print an alert box here
        UIDevice.current.setValue(UIInterfaceOrientation.landscapeLe‌​ft.rawValue, forKey: "orientation")
    }
}
```

Source: [How to detect orientation change?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25666269/how-to-detect-orientation-change)

Or put this to the view that needs to be in landscape:

```
override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    return false
}

override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.landscape
}
```

But this one cannot post an alert.

Comment: @LijithVipin - portait is locked means

Comment: @LijithVipin I don't get what you trying to say, can you elaborate?