# Screen rotate many time when change orientattion

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, orientation

I have 2 screens: the first screen support all orientations, the 2nd screen just support landscape right orientation.
I want the first screen to save its orientation before pushing to the second screen and return to that orientation when it pops back from the second screen.

my code:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:@(currentOrientaion) forKey:@"orientation"];
    [UIViewController attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation];
}
```

it's work but **sometime screen rotates many time to change orientation**.
Someone help me: why is that?

Comment: Please try changing the following  Target --> General and set Orientation Mode to Portrait only and Go To Target --> General and enable Requires fullscreen,  I've followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28938660/how-to-lock-orientation-of-one-view-controller-to-portrait-mode-only-in-swift) with above-mentioned settings to lock the orientation properly .

Comment: Try this might help your problem.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/634745/how-to-programmatically-determine-iphone-interface-orientation

Comment: also this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25666269/how-to-detect-orientation-change

Answer (score -1):

You should call these lines in some other method like `ViewDidLoad` because 
for a specific view controller, `viewWillAppear` method may call multiple times.

Comment: Gaurav - ViewDidLoad is only ever called once, when the view is loaded, so anything you add there will only apply the first time you see the view.

Comment: So in what method should we call these lines.